# Does firebase login:ci have access to all my projects?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am using the `firebase login:ci` token for CI/CD. But there is not enough documentation regarding the token.

Does it have access to all my firebase projects where my account has access or only the current active project?

Where can I see a list of all tokens and their activity?

The solution I am going for is creating a throwaway email and adding that to the project I want to deploy. Is this ok?

Comment: [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson), what is your recommendation reference to above question please? My team has multiple projects and we would like to keep `firebase ci` tokens to be scoped to respective projects, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `firebase login:ci` you get prompted to log in with a Firebase account. After picking your account, you get a dialog that shows the permissions you're granting. This contains:

> This will allow Firebase CLI to:
>
> View and administer all your Firebase data and settings

So if you click <kbd>Allow</kbd> in that dialog, the Firebase CLI will have access to all Firebase projects that the account has access to. The generated token does (as far as I know) have access to the same scope.

Comment: Is there anyway to limit the token scope for CI/CD for one specific project?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: See related issue on Github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/825

Comment: This is really sux. How can I make it secure across different environments?

Comment: I created a new Google account that only has access to select projects and use the token for that account. It'll limit the potential damage some.

Comment: It's now possible to use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var with a scoped service account. @urish link has a recent comment about it. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/825#issuecomment-685106830