# Generate firebase token with scope for github actions

Tags: firebase, token, github-actions, firebase-cli

Is it possible to create a Firebase token using the CLI that only works for a specific project inside the account? The current way using `firebase login:ci` looks like it can work for all projects inside an account. I am going to use this token for specifically Github action CI work and might pass around other team members.

- I have seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687049/does-firebase-loginci-have-access-to-all-my-projects) which was asked in 2019.
- I'm planning to use the token with [this action](https://github.com/wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action) so any workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

When you get a login token, that token represents the user, unrelated to any projects that user might have access to.

If you want to control the per-user access to various projects, you will have to configure that in the console using [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam) for each product that you are trying to control.  If you give the user permission to make changes in the console, then they implicitly have permission to make the same changes from the CLI.

Comment: Thanks Doug, but I was mistaken to say "app". I was actually referring to a project in general. For example: I manage four projects currently in my google account and wanted to generate the token just for one of them.

Comment: It's still not possible.  You have to configure per user permissions using IAM configuration in the console.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to authenticate against Firebase to deploy a service within a CI pipeline.

And you want to scope that access to a specific project only to reduce the impact radius, if the token leaks.

`firebase login:ci` has (I) a too broad scope (all projects you as a user have access to) and (II) is tied to a specific person, which does not scale well if you get ever offboarded from that project...

**The solution** is to create a **Service Account** and assign it the necessary [role(s)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles).
You will need to make the Service Account key JSON file available on your CI server and set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` respectively

The Github Action you linked provides actually the ability to authenticate via a Service Account. This means you are good to go